# How to call a webmethod within a deployment project file(dll)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have deployed a web solution project into a dll file and inside this dll I have an asmx file with **webmethods**. I have added this dll file into a aspx page and I need to call the **webmethod** using jquery ajax.

How can I call the **webmethod** if it is inside the dll?

This is how the asmx file looks like within the dll:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="MyWebServiceWS" %>

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class MyWebServiceWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
    public string Helloworld()
    { return "hello" }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: How can a web service be inside a usercontrol??? You need to be more specific and provide code samples etc.

Comment: simply use .ajax() for calling the jquery.. it does't matter weather you write javascript on page or control.. but matter when you try to access page control's data..    i have used used ajax call on my ascx control..  'WebService is not a control that you can embed on a control'

Comment: Sorry, I meant dll file not usercontrol and I added the asmx code. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the web service inside the dll? Is there no .asmx file on the server?

Comment: I am using a custom framework to add dll´s into. The dll-s are web deployment projects. Hence I want all dll resources to be inside the dll.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you access the webservices by deploying the .asmx that sits in front of the dll and hitting that page.

Have a look at this page as well:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/JsonWebServiceJQuery.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I managed to return json by calling the webmethod asmx page locally. But when I compile the project into a dll I am not sure how to call the webmethod within the dll. Any idea how I could call a webmethod/pagemethod that is located within a dll?